# Can someone tell me how can I get query parameters from a url in java that may contain ampersand in their values?

Tags: java, spring, url, url-parameters, query-string

For example for the url http:localhost:8080?v1=a&v2=b&c&v3=d
I need in this case.
v1=a   v2=b&c   v3=d
I want to do this in java only.I am actually getting this url from somewhere else so how can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: You mean i should receive the url with encoded params? Because I will only receive the url and had to extract the parameters

Answer (score 0):

You must use `URLEncoder.encode` to encode your param like this:

```
private String encodeValue(String value) {
    return URLEncoder.encode(value, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
}

public void callAPI() {
    Map<String, String> requestParams = new HashMap<>();
    requestParams.put("v1", "a");
    requestParams.put("v2", "b&c");
    requestParams.put("v3", "d");

    String encodedURL = requestParams.keySet().stream()
      .map(key -> key + "=" + encodeValue(requestParams.get(key)))
      .collect(joining("&", "http:localhost:8080?", ""));

    // call api with encodedURL
}
```

Then when you get your params, you use `URLDecoder.decode` to decode your param:

```
URLDecoder.decode(yourParam, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
```

Hope this help!

Comment: What does the joining method do? Is it an inbuilt method or I need to create it because I couldn't find it.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. joining method import from `java.util.stream.Collectors.joining`. You can read for more infomation from [Collectors.joining(CharSequence delimiter)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-)

Comment: I'm asking silly questions cause I am new to these but please bear with me. I will receive this url from some other source on which I don't have any control. My task is just to extract the params and their values. So you mean to say that I should receive the url with parameters encoded already?

Comment: If this url not from you, there are 2 cases: 1. you receive an url encoded same my answer. 2. the params is exactly url in your question then you get all param are `v1 is a`, `v2 is b`,`c is null` and `v3 is d`